# Cuando se declara una arreglo de 100 posiciones se utiliza mas memoria que si se declara uno de 10?

Tags: c#, vb

El problema es que debo guardar los resultados de una búsqueda y no se si van a ser 10 o 1000, y no quiero usar mas memoria que la que necesito. El resultado de la búsqueda son varios numero enteros, esos son los que quiero guardar.

Siento haberlos confundido, no tengo problemas con el código, el que escribí funciona bien y me da un buen tiempo de respuesta, en mi caso nunca voy a superar los 10 resultados, la pregunta se me presento cuando pensé "cuantos resultados puedo tener?" me respondí 10, y el siguiente cuestionamiento fue  "y si fueran 100?" y "si fueran 1000?", debo declarar un vector de 100? de mil?, fui a Google y no encontré respuesta y entonces busque en la comunidad, ídem, hice la pregunta.

Comment: @OscarNogales, te recomiendo que muestres parte del codigo que has intentado de la situacion que planteas.

Comment: La pregunta, como esta, es vaga. Es una buena pregunta, pero siempre será más fácil darte una respuesta útil si tiene como contexto el código en el que estás intentando resolver este problema /pregunta.

Comment: La busqueda de donde la sacas? si podes tener una cantidad de registros con esa busqueda podes darle el tamaño adecuado a tu Vector, sino podes usar un List<T> como te dejaron la respuesta, el Vector es mas rapido cuando lo recorres que un List<T>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, ocupa más memoria, lo que te recomiendo que en vez de un arreglo uses una lista así no desperdiciarás memoria, ejemplo:

```
var lista = new List<int>();
```

Y para añadir sería:

```
lista.Add(MiNumero);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si entendí bien se debe a que en la lista no defino dimensiones si no que solo utilizo las que necesito.